# Which tables/views contain the list of objects used by Service Broker?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I work with Service Broker. I need to know which Service Broker entities (message types, contracts, etc.) have been added to the database I am dealing with.

The question refers to MS SQL Server 2005.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nice article on the subject of service broker management views here...

[Troubleshooting Service Broker Problems](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/how-to-troubleshoot-service-broker-problems)